# pentaho data integrator start and end time of a transformation

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am new to PDI, my project will export data from multiple views in a postgresql database and output multiple files. One requirement is for each generated file, add two fields to show the start and end time of the transformation (from query a view to generating a file). What components/scripts to use?

Comment: You want to add start and end time as a filename or a file record inside a file, at the end or at the start of file content? That different cases.

Comment: I want to put start/end time as two fields in a separated file. This file will have all the meta data of the generated file, there are other fields (most are static text), and a field to have the number of rows in the generated text file. My original question is just about how to get start/end time.

Comment: Do you want to have start_time, then file details such as size,type,row number and end_time?

Comment: yes. no size needed, but others will be needed. So it's a process generating two files, one actual data file, and one file with all the meta data about the process (start/end date time,) and the data (number of rows).